# Twig: Render view with different parameters based on one Controller action

Tags: symfony, twig

this might be a stupid question but maybe you can still help me out here.

What I want: I have a Twig template, that has tabs in it (using Bootstrap tab panels) and now I want to render the tab contents using one Action from one Controller but with different parameters.

So basically, this controller action should take some param "type" and then return different results based on this type. The goal is to not have 2 Controllers to render the twig view that do almost the same except extracting different information based on the param "type.
However, I cannot get it to work. It's either that both tabs render the same results since apparently the view is only rendered once OR that I get exceptions in the twig template at time of rendering.
What would be the right way to approach this problem?

Many thanks.

Comment: Please update the question with the relevant code (controllers / views)

Comment: Did one of the answers answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. You can use if/else statements in your Twig template, but you can also set the template in you controller. It's up to you what suits best.

## Method 1: custom template

By default, Symfony uses 'foobar.html.twig' on your foobarAction() method, but you can override this in your method:

```
public function recentArticlesAction($max = 3)
    {
        // make a database call or other logic
        // to get the "$max" most recent articles
        $articles = ...;

        return $this->render(
            'article/recent_list.html.twig',
            array('articles' => $articles)
        );
    }
```

(warning: example from [How to Embed Controllers in a Template](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html), but the article itself has nothing to do with your question)

You can set a variable (for example `$templateName`) and change it:

```
$templateName = 'recent_list.html.twig';
if ($admin) {
    $templateName = 'another_template.html.twig';
}

//or using parameters from you Request
if ($type = $request->request->get('type')) {
    $templateName = $type . '.html.twig';
}

return $this->render(
    $templateName,
    array('articles' => $articles)
);
```

## Method 2: using Twig

Controller:

```
public function foobarAction(Request $request)
{
    return [
        'type' => $request->request->get('type');
    ];
}
```

You Twig template:

```
{% if type == 'foo' %}
<h1>Foo!</h1>
<p>Hi, welcome you the foo page!</p>
{% elseif type == 'bar' %}
<h1>Bar!</h1>
<p>Hi, you've reached the Bar page.</p>
{% else %}
<h1>Error!</h1>
<p>Type not found.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try render manually each view:

```
    if ($type) {
        return $this->render('home/template.html.twig', array('data' => $data));
    }
    return $this->render('home/another.html.twig', array('another_data' => $another_data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for the answers here, but they did not really helped me. Next time I try to add more code examples ;)

My goal was to render from **1** action into **1** template but with different parameters and render those different contents as partials in the parent view.

Example: Given a template called "view.html.twig" that includes 2 times the template "myPartial.html.twig", but first time with param and second time without param. Based on this param different contents should be returned.

My question was now, why apparently only the first action is rendered in Symfony as both my partial views had the same content.

So this is what I did now:

1 Controller, 2 Actions, both call a 3rd action to fetch the data and return the values to the calling action. Then both actions call the render method with the values rendered from the 3rd action.

This is what it looks now:

```
<div class="tab-content clearfix">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="1b">
     {% render controller('MyBundle:MyController:list1') %}
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="2b">
     {% render controller('MyBundle:MyController:list2', {'type' : 1}) %}
   </div>
```

But what I wanted to achieve was to do something like this (which did not work because then both tabs would show the same content):

```
<div class="tab-content clearfix">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="1b">
     {% render controller('MyBundle:MyController:list') %}
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="2b">
     {% render controller('MyBundle:MyController:list', {'type' : 1}) %}
   </div>
```

Which I find confusing since in both times "render" is called, so I would expect that the Controller is called in both times so that also the partial view in the controller is rendered both times. But apparently this was not the case :( The Controller itself looks something like this:

```
public function list1Action()
{
    $twigVars = //do something to build the twig vars without param;
    return $this->render('@MyBundle/Test/partial_list.html.twig', array(
        'vars' => $twigVars,
    ));
}

public function list2Action($param)
{
    $twigVars = //do something to build the twig vars with param;
    return $this->render('@MyBundle/Test/partial_list.html.twig', array(
        'vars' => $twigVars,
    ));
}
```

While what I wanted was something like this:

```
public function listAction($param = '')
{
    if ($param) {
      $twigVars = //do something to return the twig vars with param;
    } else {
      $twigVars = //do something else to return twig vars without param;
    }
    return $this->render('@MyBundle/Test/partial_list.html.twig', array(
        'vars' => $twigVars,
    ));
}
```